# A proper substitute to "highly reactive"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, expression-choice

I have to use the expression " highly reactive" a lot in my everyday writings.

- Can there be another word or phrase to put it better and which still connotes the
  correct meaning.

> [Plutonium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium) is a ("highly reactive") element.

Comment: Could hyperreactive work?: having or showing abnormally high sensitivity to stimuli

Comment: *Reactive* is a specific scientific term that means something different from its meaning in everyday speech. If you give the scientific definition in your question, we can then help with common parlance alternatives.

Comment: @bib: The "scientific definition" is effectively what they're talking about in [*How do valence electrons determine chemical reactivity?*](http://socratic.org/questions/how-do-valence-electrons-determine-chemical-reactivity-1), where they use the word ***reactive*** a lot. If there were a standard domain-specific term for "highly reactive" (which I doubt), it would surely occur there. In common parlance (including metaphoric usages) we might think that, say, ***volatile*** would work, but that already has a specific sense for chemists.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess my concern is that there are several scientific meanings for reactive. It is also used to describe magnetic reactions. I think the Q needs more context.

Comment: The word "caustic" does come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Chemistry.

> **Pyrophoric**-adj.,capable of igniting spontaneously in air.
>   (*dictionary.reference.com*)

py·ro·phor·ic (pī′rə-fôr′ĭk)
adj.

### 1. Spontaneously igniting in air.2. Producing sparks by friction.

[Origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pyrophoric)-Pyrophoric entered English in the late 1700s from the Greek root pyrophóros meaning "fire-bearing." *(etymonline.com)*

I couldn't find direct [synonyms](http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/pyrophoric) for the term pyrophoric.

> Plutonium is a *Pyrophoric* element.

Comment: In the context of what I mean by highly reactive, I think your sugegstion is helpful.'Am waiting to see some more good comments/answers.

Answer (score 3):

This being chemistry, **unstable** is commonly used in place of *highly reactive*.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unstable):

> 4. Chemistry
>      a. Decomposing readily.
>      b. Highly or violently reactive.

See also: [Chemical stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_stability)

Comment: Thankyou, I considered it, however, in the classification of elements (Chemistry), "unstable" might be too strong a word, it borderlines radioactivity (physics)

Comment: @ATHENA Sure, you've got to careful with word choices around plutonium. Perhaps use *chemically reactive* or *chemically unstable* a few times so the reader knows which realm you're discussing, then shorten things to just *reactive* or *unstable*.

Answer (score 1):

Would "volatile"be a possibility?

That would be "reactive" in the sense of unstable, but might be relevant given your context.

Comment: In chemistry, "volatile" specifically means "having a low vapor pressure."  I would avoid overloading it with other meanings.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "[element/molecule X] has a high affinity for [element/molecule Y]".

Comment: A high affinity for....being reactive?